# PEAR Return-Path

Tags: php, pear, return-path

Using PHP (5.2.17) and PEAR (CVS: $Id: Mail.php 294747 2010-02-08 08:18:33Z clockwerx $) to test Return-Path functionality. Reason: Client getting flooded with 'failure notice' messages for messages they didn't send. 
 
 My findings: Anyone using PEAR can insert **any email id** into the Header Return-Path with all failure notices routed to that path **without restrictions!** It would appear someone could flood an account with failure notices simply by spawning a series of messages which 1) are targeted towards non-existing email ids, and 2) have the "Return-Path" set to their unfortunate target. 
Am I, hopefully, missing something?